# Getting JSON Response back from MVC Controller from Ajax call

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a razor view which calls a method on an MVC controller via Ajax. All is working except I am not receiving anything back even though I am returning a JSON result. The "data" element in the success portion is undefined.

Here is the Ajax call:

```
callback: function(result) {
    if (result === true) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: "AddEmployee", // Controller/View
                data: { //Passing data
                    Name: $("#txtName").val(), //Reading text box values using Jquery
                    City: $("#txtAddress").val(),
                    Address: $("#txtcity").val(),
                    Phone: $("#txtPhone").val(),
                    SSN: $("#txtSsn").val(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.ResponseMessage);
                            //$('<div>' + data + '</div>').appendTo('#divConfirm');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddEmployee(EmpModel obj)
    {
        bool isSaved = AddDetails(obj);
        Response response = new Response {ResponseMessage = "Success!"};
        return Json(response);
    }
```

Comment: Your `success` callback function appears to be part of the `data` object

Comment: **Voting to close as a *typo***

Answer (score 0):

You put wrong } in data, my friend:

```
       Name: $("#txtName").val(), //Reading text box values using Jquery
                    City: $("#txtAddress").val(),
                    Address: $("#txtcity").val(),
                    Phone: $("#txtPhone").val(),
                    SSN: $("#txtSsn").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.ResponseMessage);
                            //$('<div>' + data + '</div>').appendTo('#divConfirm');
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phil! I am still getting used to this and I didn't even see I had the success portion in the wrong spot. That fixed it!